# Ionic 2 : Form validator (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, ionic2

I try to use validator on my form for a phone number. I try this way :

```
<input *ngIf="fieldForm.value.type == 'phone'" pattern="^([0-9]{2}\s?){5}$" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="field" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

I want to accept with space or not between two number with this pattern :

```
^([0-9]{2}\s?){5}$
```

**Example :**

```
1- 01 01 01 01 01
2- 0101010101
3- 01 0101 0101
```

Can be accepted.

**Problem :** My pattern accept only in the second form in my example. (0101010101)
I don't understand because I try my pattern in http://regexr.com/ and it work well for all my example.

An idea ?

**PS** : I want to verify a french phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is an evil beast. [Luckily I found this nice little example on regexlib.com](http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=3866)

This seems to be kind-of what you're looking for. As for why Angular isn't matching your whitespace, it may potentially be that you have to double-escape your whitespace selector, so  it would look like:

```
^([0-9]{2}\\s?){5}$
```

But that's just a guess.